# When creating a short url service, is 302 temporary redirect the best way to go?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, redirect, short-url

When creating a short URL service for URLs on the same domain, should we be using a 302 redirect?

Full URL structure: `example.com/gig/{id}/gig-full-name-slug`
Short URL structure: `example.com/g/{base64id}`

We're using asp.net mvc3, if there's any shortcuts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet is to return a 301 so that search engines pick it up as a proper redirect and dont try to index your short urls. This is what the others do (ie. bit.ly)

Answer (score 3):

As it's not a temporary redirect (as the content will never be back at that URL), a `HTTP 303 See Other` redirect would be more appropriate.

Comment: I suspect that other short URL services are using HTTP 301 Moved Permanently.  Probably because that response is cachable.

Comment: @goalie looks like you're right. I'll probably roll with the 301. Cheers.

Comment: @Ben Cull: Well, a 301 doesn't really fit, but I suppose that you have to adapt to how others (mis)use the codes rather than what the standards say...